# ArrayList<String> Error

Tags: java, arraylist, split

Hi I am having this one error that is bugging me!!

What I am trying to do is split a text file that use ";"

and after that store it an ArrayList, but this error keeps popping up!!

```
package au.edu.canberra.g30813706;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class FileReader extends Activity{{

    ArrayList<String> sInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

    String txtName = "AccomodationTxt.txt";
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File path = new File(root, "CanberraTourism/" + txtName);

    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(path)));
        String line;
        String[] saLineElements;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //The information is split into segments and stored into the array
            saLineElements = line.split(";");
            sInfo.add(saLineElements[0], saLineElements[1], saLineElements[2], saLineElements[3], saLineElements[4]);

        }
         br.close();


    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    }}

}
```

**Error:**

```
The method add(int, String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String, String)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `add` method to add multiple elements. You'll need to use `addAll`. Something like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(saLineElements[0], saLineElements[1]));
```

Using `addAll` you can add any collection of Strings to your list.

Comment: Why not `list.addAll(Arrays.asList(saLineElements).subList(0, 4));`?  Bonus points for checking that `saLineElements` contains the minimal number of elements before hand.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
sInfo.add(saLineElements[0], saLineElements[1], saLineElements[2], saLineElements[3], saLineElements[4]);
```

with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < saLineElements.length; i++) 
  sInfo.add(saLineElements[i]);
```

Comment: There are much more succinct ways to add the elements, without explicitly looping.

Comment: This solution has an advantage of having as many elements per row as it's needed

Comment: what about `addAll` as others have suggested?

Comment: Yeah, why not, with an improvement: `list.addAll(Arrays.asList(saLineElements).subList(0, saLineElements.length));`. But, then, a loop is more readable, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> sInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You cannot use [add(int, String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,E%29) to add multiple `String`.You cannot do `sInfo.add(saLineElements[0], saLineElements[1], saLineElements[2], saLineElements[3], saLineElements[4]);` .

Use [addAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) instead,

```
sInfo.addAll(Arrays.asList(saLineElements[0], saLineElements[1], 
                      saLineElements[2], saLineElements[3], saLineElements[4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared arraylist of the type string

```
   ArrayList<String> sInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
```

There is no method that is defined for arraylist like

```
    sInfo.add(String, String, String, String, String);
```

Please check the documentation below

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

You can use for loop as suggested by Boris Pavlović

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in you code, first is that you are trying to use the arraylist add method incorrectly. Second is that you are trying to store the information in a very raw way.
In object oriented programming, the correct approach is to represent data in terms of objects. As the name of file suggests, you may be trying to store accommodation related data separated by semicolons in a file. Better create a class(for eg 'Accommodation') representing the accommodation data with attributes as you have in your file separated by semicolon. Then create an Arraylist of Accommodation objects like: 
ArrayList accomList = new ArrayList

Then using your same logic of file reading and splitting each line, create and add the Accommodation objects in the arraylist like:
accomList.add(new Accommodation(saLineElements[0], saLineElements[1], saLineElements[2], saLineElements[3], saLineElements[4]))

Make sure to add an appropriate constructor in your Accommodation class.

Your code should look much better and work well if you follow OOPS concepts.

Hope it helps!